# Getting PFUser error when accessing username property when getting user as pointer

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, back4app

Getting this error:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Key "username" has no data.  Call fetchIfNeeded before getting its value.'
```

I have a joint class which contains `PFUser` as pointer. When I get a user from the joint class it just have pointer as expected but this condition fails and leads to error above:

```
if (user.username != nil) {
   username = user.username ?? "no username"
} 

/** THE ACCESSING property 
 The username for the `PFUser`.
 */
@property (nullable, nonatomic, strong) NSString *username;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen due to two reasons:

- Either an ACL is set on the user you are trying to retrieve, hence it
  is not being retrieved.So please check your ACL on the user object.
- You are not using the .includeKey() method with your query. For the
  includeKey() have a look at this guide below.

https://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/

Comment: yea in my case it was includeKey. thank you!